# how to validate neural network in tensorflow?

Tags: python, validation, tensorflow, neural-network, dataset

At the moment, my neural network only uses the training dataset to train but i want to validate as well but i cant figure out how to do that exactly. Should i run test on entire validation set after every epoch? if yes, then from the testing, i will get an accuracy but i cant figure out what to do with that either? how do i adjust the parameters based on it? do i just run the optimiser again? in this case, how is it affected by the results from the validation set?

```
 optimiser = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

  # finally setup the initialisation operator
  init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

  train = ["/Users/User/project/data/train.tfrecords"]
  dataset = d.getTrainData(train, trainSize, batch_size)
  iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
  x_batch, y_batch = iterator.get_next()


  validate = ["/Users/User/project/data/validate.tfrecords"]
  datasetV = d.getValData(validate, valSize, batch_size)
  iteratorV = datasetV.make_initializable_iterator()
  x_batch_V, y_batch_V = iteratorV.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.Saver()

        sess.run(init_op)
        e = 0
        for _ in range(epochs):
          dataset.shuffle(dataSize)
          e = e + 1
          sess.run(iterator.initializer)
          sess.run(iteratorV.initializer)
          i = 1
          try:

            while True:
              xy, z = sess.run((x_batch, y_batch))

              summary, _, c = sess.run([merged, optimiser, cost], 
                             feed_dict={x: xy, y: z})

              print ("cost of batch ", i, ": ", c)      
              train_writer.add_summary(summary, e)
              i = i + 1
          except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:

            # Raised when we reach the end of the file.
            pass

          print ("end of epoch ", e)

        save_path = saver.save(sess, "/Users/User/project/model/model.ckpt")
        print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)

      return
```

(btw i am using tensorflow version 1.2)
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need a validation set, that's different from the training set. If you don't have one consider splitting the training set using some random process to pick random examples to pick for the validation set. The only difference in your code should be that you do not run the training operation (remove `optimiser` from `sess.run`).

At the bare minimum is to run it once at the end of training and checking that the loss (and other metrics that might be important to you) are sufficiently close to the ones you get from training. The point is to make sure that you are not over-fitting on the training dataset. If you do plots you might want to want to run it from time to time to plot it with the training data. Looking at the plot is useful sometimes if you want to stop early when you see the model starts overfitting.

If you want to do hyper-parameter tuning, you would run the training with various changes to the hyper-parameters and pick the combination that gives you the best results over the validation data set. You should have a third data-set (test data set) that you can use at the very end to make sure that you don't accidentally overfit during hyper-parameter tuning.